# Java FileNotFoundException when attempting to pass a text file to a POST and converting contents to a List<Integer>

Tags: java, rest, web-services, post, http-post

I am using Java 8 and Apache HttpClient to create a RESTful web service that passes a filename as a message body. I am attempting to parse the data from the text file and add it to a List. Everything appears to work, except I am getting: `Error Parsing: java.io.FileNotFoundException: testFile.txt (No such file or directory)`.

This is the service endpoint code:

```
@POST
@Path("/fileUpload")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response fileUpload(String fileName) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            items = Arrays.asList(line.split("\n"));
        }
        List<Integer> itemNbrs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String string : items) {
            itemNbrs.add(Integer.valueOf(string));
        }
        sc.close();

        itemNbrs.forEach(System.out::println);

        // processImpl.checkItemsAndInsertIntoTable(itemNbrs);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Parsing: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Data Received: " + builder.toString());

    // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
    return Response.status(200).entity(builder.toString()).build();
}
```

The test file:

```
123
2345
4567
74543
9875
```

I have tried to pass the filename as an InputStream, and I get the same exception. I have also changed the permissions on the test file using `chmod 777`.

Stack Trace:

```
Error Parsing: java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileTest.txt
(No such file or directory)
Data Received:
```

Comment: are you passing the absolute path to file?

Comment: I have posted the stack trace. @Ruslan I have tried putting the file in it's own directory and passing the absolute path with properly escaped back slashes. Example: `//Documents//Test//fileTest.txt`. Currently I am just passing the file name and the file is in the root of my project.

Comment: The service returns a 200, and the code works when removed from the POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this at the beginning of your endpoint.

```
System.out.println(new File( fileName).getAbsolutePath());
```

You can thus see where you are currently looking for said file and adjust from there.

Comment: The stack trace now includes `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/fileTesttxt`

Comment: Well that tells you where the app is currently looking for your file

Comment: After putting the file in the directory I still get the same exception when the service is called.

Comment: is the string really coming in as "fileTesttxt", because if it is you definitely need it to be "fileTest.txt"

Comment: No. It is fileTest.txt. That was a typo.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Building on RobOhRob's answer I figured it out. Once I hit the service with `System.out.println(new File( fileName).getAbsolutePath());` at the beginning of the method it logged the absolute path as `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/fileTest.txt`.

I put the file in that directory and passed the absolute path as the message body. If you are doing this make sure you ESCAPE YOU FORWARD SLASHES! The absolute path to used in the message body of the service looks like this:

`//Applications//Eclipse.app//Contents//MacOS//fileTest.txt`